# SharePoint: SPField.FieldRenderingControl does not render if the list is from another site

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a custom New/Edit form that renders the edit controls using the FieldRendering control property of the fields. When the list and form are at the first level subsite (RootSite/SubSite1) of a SharePoint site collection. It works just fine.

When I try to use the same code to render the form in another first level subsite (RootSite/SubSite2) of the site collection, a sibling of the first site, the edit controls do not render. I have the code in (RootSite/Subsite2) and the list is still in (RootSite/SubSite1). I got a hint that RootFolder parameter might help but that did not work out. Any Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I this case you can open the root site as follows:

```
using (SPSite oSPsite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.Url))
        {
            using (SPWeb oSPWeb = oSPsite.OpenWeb())
            {
```